# how to override navigation of datagridview using enter key

Tags: vb.net

hi i have datagridview with 4 columns first three column are texbox and 4th is command button.i want to override the enter key in a datagridview so that it will set focus to the next column instead to the next row? when i reach texbox column 3 it skip command button and move on to next row here is my code

```
Class MyDataGridView
Inherits DataGridView

Protected Overloads Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Enter Then
        MyBase.ProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab)
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData)
End Function

Protected Overloads Overrides Function ProcessDataGridViewKey(ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) As Boolean
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        MyBase.ProcessTabKey(Keys.Tab)
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e)
End Function


End Class
```

this code is work fine but only problem is its also focus command button i want to skip command button . bcz command button is remove record button

Comment: try do it in cellvalidated event .. set currentcell ..

Comment: hi mat you once again trying to help me thanks please explain more if possible give me example

Answer (score 1):

my problem has been soloved i use
here is solution

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged
    If MyDataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X = 8 Then
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    End If
End Sub
```